# Avoid sending CSS with each search in CartoDB

Tags: performance, carto-js, css

We’re developing a project with CartoDB and we want to show each element with a custom image.

We are doing this setting the sublayer.setCartoCSS() with something like this:

```
cartocss: "#map { (…) }
#map[id_elem="6f86c92a-..."]{ marker-file: url(http://[domain]/Upload/image001.png);}
// ... a lot of css ...
#map[id_elem=="6f86c92a-..."]{ marker-file: url(http://[domain]/Upload/image0XX.png);}
```

And it works! :)

The problem with this solution is that we have to send the CSS of all the elements in each HTTP Request, and that’s not the most efficient way.
I have tried to set a @import as CSS, something like this:

```
cartoDBSubLayer.setCartoCSS('@import url("http://domain.com/cartodb.data.css");');
```

But it didn’t work.

Is there any way to avoid sending all the CSS in each request?

Answer (score 1):

Not loading CSS isn't supported by the HTTP standard, meaning there is no way to prevent loading it upon a request.  [This answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/71178) (along with others in that question) might help explain better.

The best way to increase CSS performance is to use minification and caching techniques. Some other techniques are explained in [this article](http://www.feedthebot.com/pagespeed/optimize-css-delivery.html).

Also, use `link` instead of `@import` to allow parallel downloads.  See [this article](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/09/dont-use-import/) for a longer description.

Comment: I still cannot vote answers, but thank you very much!